# Unable to read additional data from client session id

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hdp

We have hadoop cluster with **3 kafka** machines and **3 zookeeper** servers

hadoop version - 2.6.4 ( HORTONWORKS )

under zookeeper logs ( /var/log/zookper )

we saw a million WARN messages like:

```
2019-06-26 10:48:45,675 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory 0.000.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16b8e15a80ca681, likely client has closed socket
               at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:230)
               at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is the meaning of these messages:

```
    caught end of stream exception EndOfStreamException
    Unable to read additional data from client sessionid
```

The real problem is about the kafka machines. We faced the problem about leaders are not balanced and Kafka topics partitions finally get with leader -1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZooKeeper keeps getting EndOfStreamException, causing a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887977/zookeeper-keeps-getting-endofstreamexception-causing-a-crash)

Answer (score 0):

Try to have client retries. It solved my issue. Somehow I had retry set to zero.

For example:
`hbase.client.retries.number`