# Why kafka crash?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka 2.5.0
My service kafka crash sometimes.

**kafka/logs/server.log**

```
[09:25:23,316] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1000001a8fd0012, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
09:25:23 kafka1 systemd: kafka.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
09:25:23 kafka1 systemd: Unit kafka.service entered failed state.
09:25:23 kafka1 systemd: kafka.service failed.
```

How to find out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Check Zookeeper first if it is running.

If it is running, try to change these settings in zoo.cfg:

```
autopurge.snapRetainCount=15 (at least)
autopurge.purgeInterval=1 - 2 hours
```

Some hints might be here:

[zookeeper + Unable to read additional data from client session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777284/zookeeper-unable-to-read-additional-data-from-client-session-id)

[ZooKeeper keeps getting EndOfStreamException, causing a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887977/zookeeper-keeps-getting-endofstreamexception-causing-a-crash)

Comment: It can be nearly everything: Zookeeper might be purging too often, too many log entries, same id for 2 different zookeeper servers